# Looking for alternate function to QML ListView's itemAtIndex due to version conflict

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I'm using Qt 5.12, so I can't access ListView's [itemAtIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#itemAtIndex-method) which was introduced in Qt 5.13.
I can't upgrade Qt due to my project/platform related restrictions. Is there a way to find the item at a given index for ListView with the Qt versions prior to 5.13?

Otherwise, is there a way to get mouse positions of an item based on index?

[image]

I'm having a listview with adjacent items having different width(alternate items have same width). I'm trying to access listview's item which is of less width compared to the adjacent item. The space between two items in the above picture is also an item which is marked as dummy. I'm able to get the index of each item (both actual & dummy), but the x position I get seems to be incorrect as the rectangle cursor is not getting placed in the intended item's position.

Please suggest alternatives that gives the similar functionality as itemAtIndex. Thanks.

Comment: Check this one `<listView>.data[0].children[<index>]`.

Comment: @SMR Using the item returned, I had to take the mouse.x position & highlight something neat it. As I see, it didn't work for my current requirement. So I'm not sure if it has worked or not. But I learnt something new. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what you mean; you wanted something similar to the `itemAtIndex(<int>)` function, which the code I gave does the job. However, I believe you should clarify more of what you require in the second part.
Getting the mouse position of an item at some index requires that the item have a [HoverHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-hoverhandler.html) or that the Item position be mapped to another component with a [HoverHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-hoverhandler.html).

Comment: I have a listview with rectangle as items in it. But the catch here is that each rectangle is of different width.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the item? Perhaps if we have a clue of the use case, we can think of creative alternatives to achieve that use case without requiring absolute parity with `itemAtIndex`.

Comment: I want to find the x position of the item & place the cursor rectangle at the x.
Here is what I'm trying to do - 
I have a rectangle item which resembles a cursor.
Alternate items in the listview are designated as dummy for placing the rectangle cursor. Please note that the dummy items in the list carry less width.

Answer (score 0):

[REWRITE]

If the space of each delegate is stored in the model, we can easily use it to calculate the cursor offsets:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    property var arr: [[150,"Item1"],[140,"Item2"],[150,"Item3"],[140,"Item4"]]
    Frame {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 640
        height: 300
        ColumnLayout {
            Label { text: "cursor.index:" }
            ComboBox {
                id: comboBox
                model: 5
            }
            Label { text: "cursor.x: %1".arg(cursor.x) }
        }
        Item {
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            width: parent.width
            height: 80
            ListView {
                id: listView
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: arr
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                spacing: 10
                signal placeCursorAt(int index)
                delegate: Label {
                    id: item
                    width: modelData[0]
                    height: 80
                    text: modelData[1]
                    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                    background: Frame { }
                }
            }
            Item {
                id: cursor 
                property int index: comboBox.currentIndex
                x: getOffset(index)
                y: 0
                width: listView.spacing
                height: parent.height
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 2
                    border.color: "grey"
                    color: "red"
                }
                function getOffset(index) {
                    let offset = -listView.spacing;
                    for (let i = 0; i < index; i++)
                    offset += arr[i][0] + listView.spacing;
                    return offset;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: I have edited the question and added more info. Please see if that helps. Thank you.